# Virtualize WPF Grid bound to composite collection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, virtualization

I have a Listview that uses a grid for its ItemsPanel instead of a stackpanel (a stackpanel `won't` suffice).

The `ItemsSource` of a `grid` is bound to a `CompositeCollection` of various items; and the items, of different classes, are not ordered (i.e., first item is not necessarily in 1st row/ 1st column; it's possible that last item in the list may physically be found on the top row of the grid).

So now I am not able to use VirtualizingStackPanel,... when I check Snoop, the ListView lists all items in the ItemsSource even when they're not visible.

Question: Is there a way to virtualize contents inside of the grid?